# Compiling MariaDB and PHP still gives the header mismatch message

Tags: php, mariadb

I compiled MariaDB and PHP but I still get the following message when attempting to connect: `Warning: mysqli_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:100118 Library:50716`

My MariaDB version is `mariadb-10.1.18`.

I built it with the commands:

```
cmake \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install \
  -DWITH_INNOBASE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 \
  -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install/data \
  -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 -DWITH_BOOST=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install/boost \
  -DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install/tmp/mariadb.sock;

make;

make install;

chmod 755 scripts/mysql_install_db;
scripts/mysql_install_db --defaults-file=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install/etc/my.cnf \
  --no-defaults \
  --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp \
  --basedir=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install \
  --datadir=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install/data \
  --tmpdir=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install/tmp \
  --lc-messages-dir=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install/share
```

My PHP version is `php-5.6.20`.

I built it with the command:

```
./configure \
  --prefix=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-config-file-path=/home/stephane/programs/php-5.6.20/ \
  --with-mysqli=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install/bin/mysql_config \
  --with-pdo-mysql=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install;

make;

make install;
```

My PHP should then use the MariaDB driver provided by the compiled MariaDB. There should be no version issue.

But on the command line, the `php -i` command shows:

```
$ php -i | grep "Client API"
Client API library version => 5.7.16
Client API header version => 10.1.18-MariaDB
Client API version => 5.7.16
```

I never specified no where this `5.7.16` version. I guess it is MariaDB which gives it. Do I need to specify it somewhere ? If so, how ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

My PHP configure was using only this one `--with-mysqli=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install/bin/mysql_config` option. By not using this other `--with-mysql` option, I was leaving MySql to opt for its default driver, which is the `mysqlnd` native driver (nd). This native driver is not the one I had compiled when compiling MySql, it is one that is provided by PHP. Therefore the version mismatch.

When I then used both options, as in: `--with-mysql=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install --with-mysqli=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install/bin/mysql_config` my PHP was then using the driver compiled during the compilation of MySql. This time there could be no version mismatch.